# calloc 2 gb of memory failed for type of 'char' but succeed for 'short'

Tags: c, memory, malloc, calloc

I tried to calloc a table 2GByte large. The following code failed

```
#define MAX_FILEID      131072                  // 17 bits 131K file IDs
#define MAX_OFFSET      8192                    // offset loctions (refLoc - Loc)
#define MATCH_TAB_SIZE  (MAX_OFFSET*MAX_FILEID)

matchTab = (unsigned char*) calloc(MATCH_TAB_SIZE*2, sizeof(unsigned char));
if ( matchTab==NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "calloc %f Mbyte failed for matchTab \n", MATCH_TAB_SIZE*sizeof(unsigned char)/(1024*1024.0) );
    return;
}
else
{
    fprintf(stdout, "assigned %f Mbyte \n", MATCH_TAB_SIZE*sizeof(unsigned char)/(1024*1024.0) );
}
```

However if I replace the calloc line to

```
matchTab = (unsigned short*) calloc(MATCH_TAB_SIZE, sizeof(unsigned short));
```

It succeeded.

I am wondering why.  My machine is a 64bit linux with at least 80 gb ram.

Comment: `calloc(16384, sizeof(unsigned char))` is far from 2GB. Do you mean you call that in a loop?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected it. It should be 2^31 instead of 16384

Comment: `2 ^ 31 == 29`, `2 ^ 30 == 28`. I'm surprised either of them failed. I suspect the code you've shown is is not the code you ran. Always copy-and-paste the exact code that you actually compiled.

Comment: Sorry guys. This is my my first post. The original codes are very long. I have corrected my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8192*131072*2 = 2<sup>31</sup>

2<sup>31</sup> > `INT_MAX` in your implementation, so the above expression overflows. The result of it is undefined.

Use literals of a type that's large enough, such as `unsigned int`:

```
#define MAX_FILEID      131072U                  // 17 bits 131K file IDs
#define MAX_OFFSET      8192U                    // offset loctions (refLoc - Loc)
#define MATCH_TAB_SIZE  (MAX_OFFSET*MAX_FILEID)

matchTab = calloc(MATCH_TAB_SIZE*2U, sizeof(unsigned char));
```

Alternatively, cast the numbers to `size_t` while they are small:

```
matchTab = calloc(((size_t)MATCH_TAB_SIZE)*2, sizeof(unsigned char));
```

Note, don't cast the result of `calloc` and friends. `sizeof(unsigned char)` is always 1 so you can use `1` instead if you want.

Comment: Thank you. It worked!  Another question is why I should not cast the result of calloc. I got an error like this if I don't cast it ../source/FixedStreamReMaExd.c:337:60: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘unsigned char*’ [-fpermissive]  matchTab is defined as char *

Comment: You are using a C++ compiler. Don't.